# Shortcuts for Switching Scripts within Editor in Spyder

Tags: python, shortcut, spyder

Does anyone know the shortcuts to switch between different scripts opened in Spyder?

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is for switching to editor, but within the editor, is there any ways to switch with just keyboards?

Answer (score 3):

You can switch between files with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Pageup</kbd> / <kbd>Pagedown</kbd>, but there is still an open issue with that https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=43. For me it works fine in the currentversion.

Comment: Both Ctrl + PageUp/Down and Tab  works for me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to show a widget listing all your open files. You can filter them there too.

Answer (score 0):

in python 3.8  ,   only

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

worked for me