# Change shortcuts for Switching Scripts within Editor in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374305/shortcuts-for-switching-scripts-within-editor-in-spyder) I found the script-switching shortcuts, but I would like to change the `ctrl`+`tab` and `ctrl`+`Page up` behaviors.

However in the `tools` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` I can only find the `ctrl` + `tab` shortcut. How can I switch the two shortcuts?

**Info**: I am using Windows 10. And I installed Spyder 2.3.9 through Anaconda (2.7)

Comment: Related: On my spyder 3.0.2, Ctrl+P opens the file switcher

Comment: Note to viewers: ctrl + page up is called "cycle to next/previous file". If this is changed to ctrl + tab and ctrl + shift + tab, then spyder will cycle through tabs in the order they appear, like in a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is going to be possible in Spyder 3.1.0 (to be released in January 2017).